# Generics in C# can't find T

Tags: c#

So I'm coming from Java and is a bit confused on how to use Generics with C#. I have lambda function that should take a list and predicate (of varying object types). When I specify that I want to use generic, the compiler complains that it cannot find T. This is my lambda:

```
private List<T> LoopCompareLambda(List<T> list, Predicate<T> condition)
    {
        List<T> returnList = new List<T>();
        foreach (T sensor in list)
        {
            if (condition(sensor))
            {
                returnList.Add(sensor);
            }
        }
        return returnList;
    }
```

Comment: can you use LINQ for this?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
private List<T> LoopCompareLambda<T>(List<T> list, Predicate<T> condition)
```

The `<T>` must be *after* the method name and *before* the `(`.

Note that the signature could be (with the code you wrote):

```
private static List<T> LoopCompareLambda<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, Predicate<T> condition)
```

And in .NET there is a strong preference for using `Func<T, bool>` instead of `Predicate<T>`

```
private static List<T> LoopCompareLambda<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, bool> condition)
```

Comment: Thanks! Looked at a ton of questions but missed that one!

Answer (score 1):

Change the signiture of your method to

```
private List<T> LoopCompareLambda<T>(List<T> list, Predicate<T> condition)
```

You have to add your generic type to the method. You can use multiple generics in one method and add conditions like

```
private List<T> LoopCompareLambda<T>(List<T> list, Predicate<T> condition) where T : class, new()
```

as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your class needs to be generic.

```
class MyGenericClass<T>
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Not when he just adds the generic type to the method ;)